# Renaming multiple files by adding a string to the beginning

Tags: command-line, rename

For about 200 files in a directory I would like to add the String `1_` to the beginning of all filenames.

The filenames are, for example, `DATASET_X_Y_Z` and the result should be `1_DATASET_X_Y_Z`.

I don't know a thing about Shell scripting, but maybe there is a one liner for the terminal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796615/how-can-i-add-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-each-file-in-a-folder-in-bash

Comment: @Rinzwind link is about a different question. Macydanim question is about prepending strings to filenames, not to file contents.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

- `rename 's/^/1_/' *` for renaming all files in the current directory

or

- `rename 's/^/1_/' DATASET*` for renaming all files in the current directory starting with `DATASET` in their name

Explanation: the expression `s/^/1_/` says: "replace the beginning of the filename (that means this symbol -> `^`)' with `1_`".

Comment: If your `rename` doesn't do this out of the box, you need to install `prename` (PERL rename).

Answer (score 27):

You can easily rename all the files in current directory typing (assuming you are using bash):

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" 1_"$i"; done
```

obviously take it with care; it will remane ALL the files in the current directory that are 'visible' (filename not starting with a '.')

Comment: This is the first correct solution I found, which can be used for appending something like `.csv` to a subset of files, with a changed wild card expression instead of `*`. +1

Comment: Wow! Loops on the CLI! This is new. :)

Comment: tke it with care indeed
if you get the second i wrong: for i in *; do mv "$i" b"$1"; done
cheers to your files. you've been warned.
(I backed up the folder before trying this. fortunately).

Answer (score 10):

You can use [pyRenamer](http://www.infinicode.org/code/pyrenamer/). It can be found in the Ubuntu software center.
[image]
The original file pattern should be {X} and the renamed file pattern should be 1_{1}

Comment: One of my favourite programs